# Complexity for set

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity

this was my interview question which I got wrong and I am very confused by it.

```
fruits = {apples, grapes, oranges, pears}

for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit)
```

My thinking was we access the O(1) N times, so the time complexity is O(n). However, they said that I am incorrect and the answer is O(1). It was multiple-choice, so I did not get feedback. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Are you sure this was the exact question, iterating a full data structure is at least O(n).

Comment: Isn't this a set and not a dictionary?

Comment: Question: Which of the below answers describes the time complexity of the above code most accurately?

Comment: This **is** a set

Comment: I'd agree that since it's a set with *O(1)* access time, but then you go and access it *N* times, so it ends up *O(N)* for the whole operation. Are they asking for the characteristics of each iteration, or of all iterations? Being *O(1)* implies that a billion entries could be printed in the same time as 1, which is just plain wrong.

Comment: Unless the size of the set is to be considered a parameter, there are no inputs for the runtime of this code to depend on, so it doesn't make much sense to talk about asymptotic complexity at all. O(1) would be the most accurate, though, assuming the set is to be treated as hardcoded instead of as a changeable input.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica but you still iterate through it, don't you?

Comment: @Augustas: You do, but it doesn't matter. Asymptotic complexity isn't determined by how many loops you have or how they're nested. Asymptotic complexity is a measure of how runtime (or space, or consumption of some other resource, or whatever) depends on input. The runtime of this code does not depend on any input, as it doesn't take input.

Comment: Technically, since `apples, grapes, oranges, pears` are variables and not necessarily strings, the complexity of this code depends on how much work their `__str__` methods do. There is no way to know that from the code. If this code is an accurate copy of the question then it's a broken question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume the fruits array have a constant amount of members (4) in every case the loop will take constant time any time you use. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is O(1) *in most situations.*

Explanation:
Lookup/Insert/Delete have O(1) complexity as an average case. The reason here is they make use of Hashtable.

**How does the Hashtable do it in O(1)?** 
Whenever you try to insert a new value into a set, the value goes through a hash function and its position is decided b y that hash function. So, calculating that position is O(1) and inserting it at a known position is O(1). 
Now, when you wish to find a value *x*, you just need to know the hash function to know the position of *x*. You need not loop through all the values (which would make it O(n)).

**When is task of Lookup O(n)?**
As previously explained, you take a value, insert it into a hash function and find its position as to where you can place it. Imagine a hash function that, in some cases, places different values at the same location. So, when you try to lookup, you know the position, but you still have to do a linear search among all the elements to find the required element. Imagine the worst case "*hypothetical*" scenario when the hash function places all the elements in a single position. So, here we will again have a linear search among n elements that makes the lookup have a complexity of O(n).

Let me know in comments if you have doubts. And do like it if you gained some information.